# Cocos2dx - How to find if child is sprite or layer?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have implemented an application in cocos2dx.

The issue that i am facing currently is that i am not able to find whether the child is a sprite or a layer as the getChildren() method returns list of CCObjects.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have a child, you need to do a [typecast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) in order to check whether it's a sprite or a layer:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myNode->getChildren()->count(); i++)
{
    CCNode *child = myNode->getChildren()->objectAtIndex(i);
    CCSprite* s = dynamic_cast<CCSprite*>(child);
    if(s != 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another sample may help:

```
Vector<Node*> allNodes=this->getChildren();
for(auto&  node : allNodes){
    if(dynamic_cast<Sprite*>(node)){ //It is Sprite 
        Sprite *target=dynamic_cast<Sprite*>(node);
        //Do whatever you like
    }
}
```